# MATLAB won't extract first row & column because of matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am tracking an object that is thrown in the air, and this object governs a parabolic pattern. I'm tracking the object through a series of 30 images. I managed to exclude all the background and keep the object apparent, then used its centroid to get its coordinates and plot them. Now I'm supposed to predict where the object is going to fall, so I used polyfit & polyval. The problem is, [MATLAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) says:

> ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Now the centroid creates its own structure with a row and two columns. Everytime the object moves in the loop, it updates the first row only.

Here is part of the code:

```
For N = 1:30
    .
    .
    .
    x = centroid(1,1); % extract first row and column for x
    y = centroid(1,2); % extract secnd row and column for x
    plot_xy = plot(x,y)
    set(plot_xy,'XData',x(1:N),'YData',y(1:N));
    fitting = polyfit(x(1:N),y(1:N),2);
    parabola = plot(x,nan(23,1));
    evaluate = polyval(fitting,x);
    set(parabola,'YData',evaluate)
    .
    .
end
```

The error message I get is:

`??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`

It seems that (1:N) is causing the problems. I honestly do not know why, but when I remove N, the object is plotted along with its points, but polyfitting won't work. It gives me an error saying:

```
Warning: Polynomial is not unique; degree >= number of
data points.
> In polyfit at 72
```

If I made it (1:N-1) or something, it plots more points before it starts giving me the same error (not unique ...). But I can't remove (1:N), because I have to evaluate the coefficients of the polynomial in each loop (each value of N), so what's the solution?

Edit 2 :

This is more of my code

```
for N = 1:30
    hold on
    I = figure.image.(['j' num2str(N)]);
    bw = (I);
    imshow(bw)
    ss = bwlabel(bw);
    s = regionprops(bw,'centroid');
    centroids = cat(1, s.Centroid);
    hold(imgca,'on')
    plot(imgca,centroids(1,1), centroids(1,2),'r*')
    x = centroids(1,1);
    y = centroids(1,2);
    points = plot(x,y,'bo',x,y,'rx');
    hold on;

    for N>3
        C1 = centroids(1,1);
        C2 = centroids(1,2);
        set(points,'XData',C1,'YData',C2);
        poly = polyfit(C1,C2,2);
        parabola = plot(C1,nan(size(centroids,1),1));
        pval = polyval(poly,x);
        set(parabola,'YData',pval);
        pause(0.5)
    end
end
```

Edit 3

Code to display object distination:

```
poly = polyfit(C1,C2,2);
g = roots(poly);
v = max(g)
plot(xPlot,polyval(poly,xPlot),'y')
plot(v,'go')
```

The parabola line is plotted correctly due to xPlot, but for `g` (the prediction), it all goes wrong... Am I using the wrong syntax to get the max value?

[image]

I also realized if I put `plot(g,'g--')` instead of v, I get:
Wonder if I can get this horizontal instead of vertical. Then I will have a line with a circle where the parabola is predicted to stop.

[image]

Comment: When you set "x=centroid(1,1);", x becomes a single-element scalar. Likewise for y. I'm guessing what you probably wanted is "x=centroid(1:N,1);", which gives you the first column of array 'centroid' from 1st to Nth element. You can then replace subsequent calls of "x(1:N)" with just "x" or "x(:)".

Comment: Also, "set(plot_xy,'XData',x(1:N),'YData',y(1:N));" seems extraneous. If you've already plotted 'plot_xy' with x and y, which are supposed to be N-element vectors, there is no need to set the XData and YData properties again.

Comment: @JS, I think you should put your comments as the answer.

Comment: ZaZu: I've updated my answer for Edit #3. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your code should look like, if I correctly understand what you want to do:

```
%# if there is only one centroid per image, preassign centroid array like this
centroids = zeros(30,1); %# case A

%# if there can be any number of centroids per image, preassign like this
centroids = cell(30,1); %# case B

for N=1:30
    hold on
    I = figure.image.(['j' num2str(N)]);
    bw=(I);
    imshow(bw)
    ss = bwlabel(bw);
    s = regionprops(bw,'centroid');

    %# for case A
    centroids(N,:) = cat(1, s.Centroid);
    %# for case B
    centroids{N} = cat(1,s.Centroid);

    hold(imgca,'on')

    %# case A
    plot(imgca,centroids(N,1), centroids(N,2),'r*')
    %# case B
    if ~isempty(centroids{N})
       plot(imgca,centroids{N}(:,1), centroids{N}(:,2), 'r*');
    end

    %# I don't think the following lines do anything useful
    x=centroids(1,1); 
    y=centroids(1,2); 
    points=plot(x,y,'bo',x,y,'rx');

    %# update plots
    drawnow

   %# you can only do the fitting once you collected all centroids

end

%# case A - do nothing b/c centroids is already numeric
%# case B - catenate centroids to make a numeric array with 2 columns
centroids = cat(1,centroids{:});


    C1=centroids(:,1);
    C2=centroids(:,2);
    %#set(points,'XData',C1,'YData',C2); 
    poly=polyfit(C1,C2,2); 
    %# you can use the output of polyval directly as y-coordinate
    parabola=plot(C1,polyval(poly,C1));
```

Comment: The code gives me this error when I run it in case A : `???subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.` in case B, it works perfectly but I got two problems. The x and y you mentioned that may not be useful are actually there to plot each ball's current and previous position and keep it there ... When I comment out x y and their plotting, I get the ball to move and then the parabola is shown AFTER it finishes ... When I keep the x and y + plotting, I get `??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.` ... any ideas ?

Comment: Ok I got the x and y to not show the index exceeds matrix dimensions .. So it works now, all I need to do is put the parabola plotting in a loop so that it shows (live-time) as the object is being plotted along the screen

Comment: Okay I got the x and y not to show that index exceeds matrix dimensions .. I just changed how it extracts rows n cols from the array... Now what I need is, whenever a new image is posted (position change when N+1), I want the previous position plotted by x and y to stay ... this works only after the 23 loop is completed via the command `set(points,'XData',C1,'YData',C2);` that you commented out .. but when I put the code you have there that is after the loop, IN my loop of 1 to 23, I get `??? Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object. ` ... any ideas ?
`

Comment: Okay, this code `centroids = cat(1,centroids{:})` is the one causing the previous error (non-cell array object) .. Im guessing its because of the {:} ??

Comment: @zazu: did you check whether you're doing case A or case B? The `cat` line is only for case B

Comment: @zazu: in case it wasn't clear: If you go with case A (only 1 centroid per image), remove all code labeled `case B`

Comment: Thanks for replying Jonas, im using Case B ... It works well but as mentioned before, when I put the command in the loop I get that cell contents reference error ...

Comment: Oh, now I understand! Yeah, you can't do that. Instead, inside the loop, call `currentCentroid = cat(1,centroids{:})`, and for plot, use `plot(currentCentroid(:,1),currentCentroid(:,2)`. Otherwise, after the first catenation, centroid turns from a cell array into a double, and in the next iteration, Matlab errors because it expects centroids to be a cell array.

Comment: Okay thank you very much !! I got it to work now .. There is one thing though, I was expecting the parabola (polyfit) line to plot all the way till the end (as a prediction where the ball will fall) just after 3 loops .. why doesnt this happen ? Instead, it just plots a line step by step as the ball is moving (one image to another) ...

Comment: @ZaZu: polyval calculates y-points only for the x-points you give to it. Thus, you may want to define a vector `xPlot` that goes from your starting `x` to some large number (or you can redefine it at every iteration to run from the starting `x` to the point where the parabola hits the ground). Then, you plot using `plot(xPlot,polyval(poly,xPlot))`

Comment: Do i have to replace plot by anything else ? Or can I just add it as an extra code ? Because I made xplot=Centroids(:,1) but that didnt work =\ ***EDIT*** I made xPlot=C2, and the prediction starts plotting from left to right (from where the object hits the ground, going upwards) ... No idea why

Comment: EDIT -- Well you said `starting x to some large number`, so I thought ill make xPlot = 1:500 .. Well that worked but the plot is out of range, which I guess is incorrect .. its continuing to plot the parabola even after the hitting point.

Comment: It looks like you want to calculate the point where the parabola hits the ground. Since the parabola hits the ground when `y=0`, you can use `roots` (http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/roots.html) to find the corresponding x-coordinates (if the target is above ground at `yTarget`, use `roots(poly+[0,0,yTarget])` instead). Since it's a parabola, you know there will be two roots. If you know that the parabola goes from left to right, use `max` to find the root with the largest x-coordinate and store it in `myRoot`. Then you can create `xPlot` as `1:myRoot`.

Comment: @Jonas, Im kind of confused regarding the code you mentioned, where would I use `max` ?? Do I replace it somewhere in the code ? Because I know that the parabola always goes from right to left in my case.

Comment: A parabola has two roots, i.e. two x-values where the y-value of the parabola is zero. You want your vector xPlot to go from, say, 1 to the rightmost root. To find the rightmost root, you take the maximum of the two roots returned by `root`.

Comment: Oh im sorry I think I got confused to what you're actually talking about, are you referring to plotting the parabola itself ? Because I managed to do that .. I was referring to adding a point ( i.e ----O ) to mark the destination where the parabola ends (predicted location) of the falling object.

Comment: You can do that the same way: find the roots of the parabola, select the larger of the two. This is the predicted location of the falling object.

Comment: I really thank you for keeping up with me all this time, I really appreciate it alot !! Means loads to me !! Plus im learning new code which is always nice :)  I have updated the code, please look at the question **EDIT3** , this is my last problem !!

Comment: The root is just the x-value. The corresponding y-value is 0. Thus:
`plot(v,0,'r*')`

Comment: Thank you, but it still plots in the middle, using this method, the point is above the curve(but still in the middle) ... whyyyy ?

Answer (score 1):

**[Answer edited to reflect updates]**

In your code, you used

```
C1=centroids(1,1);
C2=centroids(1,2);
```

After this step, C1 and C2 become single-element scalars. You can check this with `size(C1)` and `size(C2)`, which will return `[1 1]` as the answer. I'm guessing that you wanted to plot the first C1- and C2-point, then extend it all the way to element pair N. That's not necessary, the `plot` function can handle vectors (and even matrices, but that will appear as a series of plots).

I'm not familiar with the image processing toolbox, and I do not have that toolbox so I can't check the function outputs. But as far as I can tell, what you need is a 30-row 2-column array of centroid position data, from which you will curve-fit its position at unknown x. I've removed some plotting functions; I trust this will make the code clearer.

```
for N=1:30
    I = figure.image.(['j' num2str(N)]);
    bw=(I);
    ss = bwlabel(bw);
    s = regionprops(bw,'centroid');
    centroids = cat(1, centroids, s.Centroid); %Concatenate s.Centroid below centroids
end

%At this point, "centroids" should be a 30-by-2 array
size(centroids) % check if the output from this is [30 2]

x=centroids(:,1);
y=centroids(:,2);
poly=polyfit(x,y,2); %poly is a vector of curve-fitted polynomial coefficients
pval=polyval(poly,x); %pval is a vector of curve-fitted values evaluated at x
parabola=plot(x,pval); %plot the parabola
```

To get the y-position of the parabola at a point x_i, use `polyval(poly,x_i)`.

Note particularly the proper syntax for the `cat` function; cat(A,B) concatenates B below A, you can't use `cat` with only one argument, as in your original code. This is likely the root cause of your headache, since with only 1 argument MATLAB simply takes "s.Centroid" as your new "centroids" array instead of adding it below the existing "centroids" array.

**Reply to EDIT #3**

In this part of your code

```
poly=polyfit(C1,C2,2); %'poly' is a vector of polynomial coefficients
g=roots(poly); %g solves for polynomial roots
v =max(g) %v is the largest root (assumed to be the expected ground-level destination)
plot(xPlot,polyval(poly,xPlot),'y') %plots polynomial at given x-values

%here, one expects to plot a point for the expected destination.
%the call to the plot function should follow syntax similar to the previous line
plot(v,'go') %plot function has syntax plot(x,y,options)
%therefore it should look like plot(v,polyval(poly,v),'go')
```

I've added some comments. The problem is with the line where you called `plot` to plot the expected destination; the syntax seems to be wrong. If only 1 data argument is given, MATLAB assumes the given data to be the y-value, using its array index as the x-value (i.e. plotting y(1) at 1, y(2) at 2, etc). This is not what you want for variable v.

You can also use `plot(v,0,'go')` as mentioned by Jonas, but it never hurts to double-check if the extrapolated polynomial value is actually near 0 ;)

Comment: Thanks for answering.. Im getting an error `Warning: Polynomial is not unique; degree >= number of data points. > In polyfit at 72` ... Why is this happening ?

Comment: For which value of N are you getting this error? I'm guessing it would probably be N=1 or N=2. This is simply because you can't do polynomial curve-fitting with only 1 or 2 points, there is insufficient information :)

Comment: Yes at N=1 ... as soon as it starts polyfitting basically ... I think its because the centroids store data in one row only .. it overwrites in every loop..For example, I expect to get 23 rows by the end of the code, but all I get is 1 row with the last coordinates of the centroid .. is this why its not working ???

Comment: Looking at the original question again, there's a point I would like to clarify: You have 30 images and hence 30 corresponding centroids. You also mentioned that the "centroid" array creates its own structure with a row and 2 columns? Can you get the "centroid" array created as 30 rows and 2 columns, each row belonging to one image in the sequence?

Comment: I want the centroid array to get 30 rows, its not ... I assume thats why its crashing .. I uploaded a big snippet of my code, check it please

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, I will try and work it out from your help :)

Comment: Thanks for adding an additional answer, unfortunately I get the point in the middle when I use this way :( Its similar to the picture but higher (above the curve)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you may be confusing yourself with x and y and you might do better without them.  Here's how I would rewrite your code, if I have understood your intentions correctly.  Note especially the rewritten polyfit call.  I also think that you have hard-coded the call to nan incorrectly, so I have 'corrected' that too:

```
For N=1:30
.
.
.
plot_xy=plot(centroid(1,1),centroid(1,2))
set(plot_xy,'XData',centroid(:,1),'YData',centroid(:,2); 
fitting=polyfit(centroid(:,1),centroid(:,2),2);
parabola=plot(centroid(:,1),nan(size(centroid,1),1));
evaluate=polyval(fitting,centroid(1,1));
set(parabola,'YData',evaluate)
.
.
end
```

Comment: Thanks for replying !!! I did what you mentioned in your code, but I get the same error of polynomial : `Warning: Polynomial is not unique; degree >= number of data points. > In polyfit at 72` ... I just dont get whats up with this polynomial error

Comment: Post some sample data, I'll try it if I have time later.